# Enable sluggified URLs in Django

Tags: django, url, slug

I am trying to enable sluggified URLs in Django of the form that SO uses: example.com/id/slug.
I have no problem enabling slugs, and have URLs currently set up of the form: http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/id/ (eg. /articles/1/) and that works fine. The corresponding URLpattern is:

```
(r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/$',  'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail', info_dict),
```

If I change the URL pattern to:

```
(r'^(?P<slug>\d+)/$',  'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail', info_dict),
```

Then I recieve the following eror when I navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/another-article/:

> The current URL, articles/another-article/, didn't match any of these.

If, however, I try:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/1/
```

I get the error:

> No article found matching the query

Ultimately I want to be able to navigate to an aricle via either:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/1/
>   or
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/1/another-article/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I should have been just a little more patient before asking this question because I figured out the answer:

```
(r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/$',  'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail', info_dict),
(r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',  'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail', info_dict),
```

The first pattern allows URLs of the form /articles/1/ which means that the second urlpattern (to include the slug) is optional.

Comment: yeah, you were missing the regex pattern match for the actual slug.